# jQuery and rotation of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, rotation

I have two divs with a class each set. Both these divs occur several times on my website. It looks like below:

```
<div class="player"><div class="theplayer"></div></div>
```

I want to be able to click "theplayer" and rotate that div. This I have managed, but when I rotate it and then start to rotate another div with the same class the "new" div will be set to the same angle (+35), as the previously rotated div. Any way around this? I can't really use id instead of class since there will be alot of these div's.

Below is the jQuery that I've found somewhere:

```
var rotation = 0;

jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
    return $(this);
};

$(".theplayer").click(function() {;

    rotation += 35;
     $(this).rotate(rotation);
});
```

Really appreciate all help!

Comment: What do you want the new div to rotate from? You're setting the initial angle `rotation`, should that be something else?

Comment: When I click the divs I want them to go +35 from their current angle. Currently they go +35 from where the last clicked div was.